# Implementing genetic algorithm from Apache Commons Math library

Tags: regression, genetic-algorithm, apache-commons-math

I am trying to implement genetic algorithm from Apache Commons Math library. I would like to use it together with OLS or GLS regression from the same package.
But I have no idea how to do it. Could anyone help with some ideas?

Comment: Since Apache Common 3 you have one out of the box: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/genetics.html To me the interface is extendable enough to handle most situations. Since its a very old algorithm I would suggest to use it directly instead of reinventing a very old wheel.